# How do you change the Window Icons in QGIS 1.7

Tags: qgis, icon

I am a beginner to QGIS 1.7, and I want to change the icon files in QGIS, (wherever we see the 'Q' icon I have to change that). I tried and I got success in the case of the mainWindow, and also somewhere it was reflecting but the problem was with menuitem named 'Layer'.

When ever I trigger 'add postgis layer' a widget opens but the icon 'containing Q' was still there...

So could you suggest a method through which I can change all the window Icons in the  QGIS with the icons that I want?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I guess you could exchange the icon (keeping the name) and build QGIS from source with the new icon.

Comment: there are so many icons with different names and also in the different file formats ... so how come i will be knowing that which file i have to modify ...

Answer (score 7):

There is a good blog post on branding QGIS by one of the lead developers (Tim Sutton of Linfiniti) here - [Building 
Custom QGIS Installers for Windows](http://linfiniti.com/2011/05/building-custom-qgis-installers-for-windows/).

It details how to customise the Splash Screen, and the title of the application. As underdark pointed out in her comment, you should be able to edit or replace all the QGIS icons and recompile to update this also.

To find icons you could search for all the images in the source folders and show them as thumbnails.

You may have received downvotes for wanting to "hide" the QGIS branding, but in my opinion and in the opinion of the developers, opensource should allow you to take and reuse code as you need it.

> With all the flexibility that QGIS offers, being open source and 'out
>   there' for anyone to hack on, its easy to take what the project
>   provides and rebrand it substantially
>
> - you can create a custom icon theme
> - you can remove unwanted user interface elements
> - you can replace help text, about text etc
> - you can rename the application itself to something else
> - you can change the application icon

But as Tim Sutton points out:

> One thing you may not do is claim the fundamental work to be your own.
>   Any time you make a publically available custom version of QGIS, be
>   sure to remember that you need to redistribute the full source code
>   (including all your customisations) with it in order to comply with
>   the letter and spirit of the GPL.

A final point though - you may want to point out to the client that the development time used to brand QGIS, and then maintain your customisations as new versions of QGIS are released, may be better spent meeting their GIS rather than marketing requirements.

Comment: Great answer - only one comment - the issue of future QGIS updates. Rebranded versions demand constant work (in keeping up with the "vanilla" versions) - this should be discussed with the customer early on.

Comment: I'd imagine the application title is set or refreshed in many different places in the code and to override this everytime could be more work than editing the source (or convincing the client it is not worth it).